# SignalR long polling fails on production

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, signalr

The GET request fails on a client in a Web Application, Does anybody have any info on this or have faced such an issue in SignalR.
The Setup works all good on a Development environment, in Production it fails

[image]

Comment: Looks like server sent events to me

Comment: dfowler: is there any way i could check to resolve this issue, is there any specific configuration i need to adhere to in the IIS?

Comment: what is the http response status code and body?